# Django 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle

I am making the database call to bring a BLOB type image to the django view, but I get the error "'str' object has no attribute 'read'".

views.py

```
def listar_productos():
        django_cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor = django_cursor.connection.cursor()
        out_cur = django_cursor.connection.cursor()
    
        cursor.callproc('FASTFERIA.SP_LISTAR_PRODUCTOS', [out_cur])
    
        lista = []
        for fila in out_cur:
            data = {
                'data': fila,
                'imagen':str(base64.b64encode(fila[7].read()),'utf-8')
                }
            lista.append(data)
    
        return lista
```

At first I got the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'", I fixed this by changing the row number where the image attribute is located.

```
'imagen':str(base64.b64encode(fila*[7]*.read()),'utf-8')
```

By the way, I am working with stored procedures from django to oracle, here is the PA of the 'listar'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FASTFERIA.SP_LISTAR_PRODUCTOS (productos out SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS 
BEGIN
    OPEN productos FOR SELECT * FROM productos;
END;
```

If you could help me understand what the error is trying to say, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: From the sound of it I would guess that fila[7] - whatever that is - is null

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Apparently, `fila[7]` is a string, not an object that you can call `read()` on.  Have you looked at the data in `fila` for each iteration through your data?  Put a breakpoint in your debugger (you're able to use a debugger I hope) at the line that produces the error and look at what is in `fila`.

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini It is supposed that 'fila[7]' is where the image attribute is positioned, when I change that data, I get the other error I mentioned, which is "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'".

Comment: @CryptoFool Thanks!, I don't think I can use a debugger with this